# Delete array element via key pair condition php laravel

Tags: php, arrays, object

Hi I have an object array in a variable `$questions` which is

```
$questions = Question::where('isenabled', '=', 'Yes')->orderBy('sortorder', 'asc')->get();
```

This has fields like `id, question, status`.

I know I can delete an element using `unset()` but it's paramater is the key number value or it's position from the array. Is it possible to delete an element using for example a `id` value. Let's say I want to delete an array element with the `id` with the value of `135`

Answer (score 0):

you can use eloquent collection to avoid an id,like this

```
$questions = $questions->reject(function ($questions) {
return $questions->id === 135;
})
```

for more see the details https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections